# Como validar que un campo email tenga un formato correcto de email?

Tags: trigger

Debo crear la tabla Speaker con los siguientes campos: speaker_code, speaker_name, email, birth_date
Donde birth_date tiene formato YYYY-MM-DD (por ejemplo: '1990-06-15').
El campo speaker_code es la llave primaria.

Restricciones:

- speaker_name no puede ser null.
- email debe validar si tiene un formato correcto de email.
- birth_date no puede ser superior a la fecha del sistema.

No se puede utilizar herramientas de generación automática de código. No se pueden declarar las restricciones a posteriori; no se puede utilizar ALTER TABLE para añadir restricciones después de la creación de las tablas). Hay que darle nombre a todas las restricciones.  Todo se debe realizar por consola.

Cómo creo la tabla con esas restricciones?

Comment: Agrega lo que has intentado, de paso edita y en las etiquetas por favor agrega que motor estas usando